# Python Clean way to get whether a number is above/below two values and increment accordingly

Tags: python

Consider (simplified)

```
low_count = 0
high_count = 0
high = 10
low = 5
value = 2
```

What is a clean way to check a number `value` versus a min `low` and a max `high`, such that if `value` is below `low` `low_count` increments, and if `value` is above `high` `high_count` increments? Currently I have (code snippet)

```
            high_count = 0
            low_count = 0
            low = spec_df['Lower'][i]
            high = spec_df['Upper'][i]
            #Calculate results above/below limit
            for result in site_results:
                if result<low:
                    low_count+=1
                else:
                    if result>high:
                        high_count+=1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `elif` instead of `else:\nif`.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it as

```
low_count = sum(map(lambda x: x < low, site_results))
high_count = sum(map(lambda x: x > high, site_results))
```

but admit I'm spoiled by Haskell.

**Edit**: As suggested by @Nick Burns, using list comprehension will make it even clearer:

```
low_count = sum(x < low for x in site_results)
high_count = sum(x > high for x in site_results)
```

Comment: +1 - I agree that this is far more pythonic in this example. However, would probably use a simple generator inside sum: `sum(x for x in site_results if x < low)`

Comment: I agree that the list comprehension is even clearer, but I believe you meant ``len``, not ``sum`` (since the count of low-value elements is needed); it will also require wrapping the comprehension in list, since you can't take ``len`` of a generator. Alternatively, you can write ``sum(x < low for x in site_results)``

Comment: sorry -good point. This was a typo, meant to read: `sum(1 for x in site_results if x < low)` . I which case, no need for a list :)

Comment: wouldn't this code be poor performing once you get a huge number of items in `site_results`? I'm thinking this is four linear, a.k.a. `O(n)`, operations, since `sum` and `map` are `O(n)`...is this incorrect?

Comment: @omouse: not four, but only two, since ``map`` or list comprehensions return iterators, not lists. Yes, in my solution technically there will be more additions (you will add ``False`` values too), but @Nick's solution does not have this drawback. Finally, it's still O(N), same as the original code, and in the very unlikely event the different coefficient matters, it will be picked up during profiling. I prefer to optimize for humans first.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the fact that Python can interpret boolean values as integers:

```
for result in site_results:
    low_count  += result < low
    high_count += result > high
```

If those conditions evaluate to `True`, this will add `1` to the counts, otherwise `0`. This is the same principle as used in the list comprehensions by Bogdan and Nick Burns:

```
high_count = sum(result > high for result in site_results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty clean. I would edit the following:

```
elif result>high:
   high_count+=1
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html
Is the code not working for you or are you just looking for a better way?

Comment: There is no `elseif` in Python. It's `elif`.

Comment: Right you are, good eye! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way would be:

```
 for result in site_results:
     if result<low:
        low_count+=1
     elif result>high:
        high_count+=1
```

Comment: Truly pythonic code would follow PEP8, particularly [with regards to spacing](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

For a more complex case, I'd write a function and use a `Counter`. For example:

```
def categorize(low, high):
    def func(i):
        if i < low:
            return 'low'
        elif i > high:
            return 'high'
        else:
            return 'middle'
    return func

site_results = list(range(20))

counts = collections.Counter(map(categorize(5, 10), site_results))
print(counts['high'], counts['low'])
```

But for a trivial case like this, that would be silly. Other than tenstar's/minitech's suggestions, I wouldn't do anything different.

Comment: Wow - I was playing with: `print Counter({-1: 'low', 1: 'high'}.get(cmp(result, low), 'eq') for result in site_results)`

Comment: @JonClements: If you want to one-liner-ize it, you'd need something like `(cmp(result, low) + cmp(result, high)) // 2`, which I think goes way beyond the bounds of readability…